# Как комбинировать стили в RichTextBox (жирный, курсив, подчеркивание)?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Возникла небольшая проблема. Есть 3 кнопки: жирный, курсив и подчеркивание. При нажатии на каждый из них, автоматически меняется стиль выделенного текста. Проблема заключается в том, что к примеру после нажатия на "жирный" нажимаю на "курсив" и выделенный текст принимает стиль курсива и сбрасывает активный жирный. Перепробовал очень много способов. Максимум выходит применить одновременно 2 стиля, до 3 не доходит. Сразу скажу, что я пытался в условии задать на проверку одновременно 2 стиля. Условие не работает, программа не может понять какие стили выделены одновременно. Вот код.

```
    private void bold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Italic)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Underline)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Regular)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
        else
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Underline);
        ContentBox.Select();
    }

    private void italic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Bold)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold);
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Underline)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Underline);
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Regular)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic);
        else
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
        ContentBox.Select();
    }

    private void underline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Bold)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Italic)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Italic);
        if (ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Regular)
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
        else
            ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
        ContentBox.Select();
    }
```

Скажите, как добиться того же результата что и в ворде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы вам не попробовать

```
private void bold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold | ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style);

    ContentBox.Select();
}
```

Или

```
private void bold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(ContentBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold ^ ContentBox.SelectionFont.Style);

    ContentBox.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с помощью winapi.
Этот код позволяет применять стиль для выделения, содержащего разные стили вперемешку. Уже имеющееся форматирование не теряется.

```
 [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
                int msg, int wParam, ref CHARFORMAT lp);

        private const int EM_SETCHARFORMAT = 1092;
        private const int EM_GETCHARFORMAT = 0x0400 + 58;


        private const int CFM_BOLD = 1;
        private const int CFM_ITALIC = 2;
        private const int CFM_UNDERLINE = 4;

        private const int SCF_SELECTION = 1;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct CHARFORMAT {
            public int cbSize;
            public uint dwMask;
            public uint dwEffects;
            public int yHeight;
            public int yOffset;
            public int crTextColor;
            public byte bCharSet;
            public byte bPitchAndFamily;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
            public char[] szFaceName;

            // CHARFORMAT2 from here onwards.
            public short wWeight;
            public short sSpacing;
            public int crBackColor;
            public int LCID;
            public uint dwReserved;
            public short sStyle;
            public short wKerning;
            public byte bUnderlineType;
            public byte bAnimation;
            public byte bRevAuthor;
        }
        private void SetCharFormatMessage(ref CHARFORMAT fmt)
        {
            SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, ContentBox.Handle), EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref fmt);
        }

        private void ApplyStyle(uint style, bool on)
        {
            CHARFORMAT fmt = new CHARFORMAT();
            fmt.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(fmt);
            fmt.dwMask = style;

            if (on)
                fmt.dwEffects = style;
            SetCharFormatMessage(ref fmt);
        }

        private void BoldCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyStyle(CFM_BOLD, (sender as CheckBox).Checked);
        }

        private void ItalicCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyStyle(CFM_ITALIC, (sender as CheckBox).Checked);
        }

        private void Underline_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyStyle(CFM_UNDERLINE, (sender as CheckBox).Checked);
        }

        private void ContentBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Чтобы синхронизировать выделение и кнопки
            CHARFORMAT cf = new CHARFORMAT();
            cf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(cf);
            SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, ContentBox.Handle), EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref cf);
            BoldCheckbox.Checked = (cf.dwEffects & CFM_BOLD )== CFM_BOLD;
            ItalicCheckbox.Checked = (cf.dwEffects & CFM_ITALIC) == CFM_ITALIC;
            UnderlineCheckbox.Checked = (cf.dwEffects & CFM_UNDERLINE) == CFM_UNDERLINE;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Двойная рекурсия FTW!

Comment: В чём отличие от уже существующей обёртки-то?

Comment: >VladD где? CheckedChanged меняется только если пользователь нажал на кнопку, а не программно

Comment: @Discord позволяет применять стиль для выделения, содержащего разные стили вперемешку. Именно то, чего хочет автор.

Comment: @VladD где рекурсия?

Comment: Ну, вы цитируете ответ @Discord, который в свою очередь ссылается на ответ @VladFromMoscow. Ну да, не рекурсия в строгом смысле, но в бытовом — вполне.`

Answer (score 0):

Контрол не поддерживает эту фичу в нормальном виде. Вам придётся пройтись по всему выделению посимвольно и приминять стиль. `SelectionFont` задан, только если *во всём выделении один и тот же стиль*.

Если вам не нужно делать жирным текст, который только наполовину подчёркнутый, например, то достаточно применять маски, как предложил @VladFromMoscow. Но этот код будет недостаточно универсален. Скажем, вы можете изменить стиль в этом случае (квадратные скобки — выделение):

> **bold** [**bold**] **bold**

на это:

> **bold** [***bold italic***] **bold**

Однако попытка изменить это:

> **bold** [**bold** normal] **bold**

закончится в лучшем случае так:

> **bold** [*bold normal*] **bold**

Более полноценное решение вы можете найти в вопросе [How do I maintain RichText formatting (bold/italic/etc) when changing any one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5325918)

Comment: Ну хотя бы что-то. Трудновато работать с неполноценным "RichTextBox". Благодарю за ответ.